# Displaying a decimal value on a windows form

Tags: c#, .net, decimal

I need help with displaying a decimal value on a Windows Form.

I have a class with a method to calculate an interest amount, listed below.

```
public virtual decimal CalculateInterest()
{
    interest = (interestRate/100) * base.getBalance();
    return interest;
}
```

In my main form, I am using this method when a button is clicked, listed below.

```
private void btnCalcInt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   decimal endBalance;
   decimal intRate;
   decimal getIntGained;

   endBalance = Convert.ToDecimal(lblSaveEndingBalance.Text);
   intRate = Convert.ToDecimal(lblSaveIntRate.Text);
   SavingsAccount CalcInt = new SavingsAccount(endBalance, intRate);

   getIntGained = CalcInt.CalculateInterest();
   lblSaveInterest.Text = getIntGained.ToString();
}
```

In the last line `(lblSaveInterest.Text = getIntGained.ToString();)`, how do I tell it to display only 2 positions after the decimal place?

Or, can someone help with this scenario?  On my Windows form, I have a text box that represents a percent.  Currently, the user could enter a value of `2` or `.02`.  How can I code this to only all `.02`?  By doing this, I could then modify the method in my class and remove the division of 100.

Answer (score 5):

For the first part, you can use either this:

```
lblSaveInterest.Text = getIntGained.ToString("#,###.00");
```

Or this:

```
lblSaveInterest.Text = getIntGained.ToString("G");
```

**EDIT:** For the second part, you can add a validation rule for the textbox to display a messagebox if the number is greater than 1.0 (100%) when the textbox loses focus.

Answer (score 2):

I'd also do [`Decimal.TryParse(string, Decimal)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557.aspx) instead of `Convert.ToDecimal()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Decimal.Round()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4e2bye2.aspx):

```
lblSaveInterest.Text = Decimal.Round(getIntGained,2).ToString();
```